# How to convert the mouse position in pixels into the row and column on the grid?

Tags: java, processing

I am basically making a battleship guessing game where you have to the position of a ship by the click of your mouse. When a position of the ship is guessed correctly it deletes that ship cell from the array and when every cell is guessed correctly, the game is over.

What I am now struggling on is to

1. keep the ship cells within the canvas
2. convert the mouse position in pixels into the row and column on the grid
3. if the guess is correct, add the guess to the hit array and if missed adding it to the miss array.
4. when a guess is made, in addition to colouring the cell, print either “Hit!” or “Miss!” on the cell
5. sinking the ship when all cells have been hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you've mixed rows and columns. The x coordinate goes from the left to the right, this are the columns. The y axis goes from the top to the bottom and corresponds to the rows.

Don't store `column`, `row`, `hit` and `miss` in arrays. But use 2-dimensional arrays to store the position of the ship and the positions of mouse clicks:

```java
boolean [][] ship;
boolean [][] click;
```

> 1. keep the ship cells within the canvas

If the direction is horizontal, then the x start position of the ship has to be less than `NUM_COLS - shipLength`:

```java
randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS - shipLength);
randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS);
```

If the direction is horizontal, then the y start position of the ship has to be less than `NUM_ROWS - shipLength`:

```java
randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS);
randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS - shipLength);
```

Call `randomShip` in `setup` rather than `draw`:

```java
void setup() {
    size(600, 500);
    randomShip();
    println(store);
}

void draw() {
    // randomShip(); <---- delete
    drawCells (row, column, shipLength, (255) );
}
```

Generate the random position and size of the ship in `randomShip`;

```java
void randomShip () {

    ship = new boolean[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
    click = new boolean[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];

    shipLength = (int)random (3, 8);

    int store = (int)random(vert, horz);  
    if (store >= 0) {

        int randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS - shipLength);
        int randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS);

        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++ ) {
            ship[randomX + i][randomY] = true;
        }
    } else  {

        int randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS);
        int randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS - shipLength); 

        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++ ) {
            ship[randomX][randomY+1] = true;
        }
    }
    println(shipLength);
}
```

> 2. convert the mouse position in pixels into the row and column on the grid
> 3. if the guess is correct, add the guess to the hit array and if missed adding it to the miss array.

The cell which was clicked can be get by the dividing the mouse coordinates `mouseX` and `mouseY` by `CELLSIZE`

```java
int cell_x = mouseX / CELLSIZE; 
int cell_y = mouseY / CELLSIZE;
```

Store mark the clicked cells and count the hits and miss in `mouseClicked`:

```java
void mouseClicked () {

    int cell_x = mouseX / CELLSIZE; 
    int cell_y = mouseY / CELLSIZE;

    if (!click[cell_x][cell_y]) {
        click[cell_x][cell_y] = true;

        if ( ship[cell_x][cell_y] ) {
            hitCount ++;
        } else {
            missCount ++;
        }
    }
}
```

> 4. when a guess is made, in addition to colouring the cell, print either “Hit!” or “Miss!” on the cell

Evaluate the ship position (`ship[][]`) and clicked positions (`click[][]`) in drawCells. Draw the cells and the text dependent on the states in 2 nested loops:

```java
void drawCells(int colour) {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {

            float x = i * CELLSIZE;
            float y = j * CELLSIZE;

            if (ship[i][j]) {
                fill (colour);
                rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE);
            }

            if (click[i][j]) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                textSize(15);
                text(ship[i][j] ? "hit" : "miss", x+10, y+30); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 5. sinking the ship when all cells have been hit

Handle the end of the game in `draw`:

e.g.

```
void draw() {

    drawCells(255);

    if (hitCount == shipLength ) {

        // [...]

    }
}
```

---

Full code listing:

```java
final int CELLSIZE = 50;
final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
final int NUM_COLS = 12;

int horz = (int)random(50);
int vert = (int)random(-50);

int store;
int shipLength;

boolean [][] ship;
boolean [][] click;

int hitCount = 0;
int missCount = 0;

void setup() {
    size(600, 500);
    randomShip();
    println(store);
}

void draw() {

    drawCells(255);

    if (hitCount == shipLength ) {

        // [...]

    }
}

void drawCells(int colour) {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {

            float x = i * CELLSIZE;
            float y = j * CELLSIZE;

            if (ship[i][j]) {
                fill (colour);
                rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE);
            }

            if (click[i][j]) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                textSize(15);
                text(ship[i][j] ? "hit" : "miss", x+10, y+30); 
            }
        }
    }
}

void randomShip () {

    ship = new boolean[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
    click = new boolean[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
    hitCount = 0;
    missCount = 0;

    shipLength = (int)random (3, 8);

    int store = (int)random(vert, horz);  
    if (store >= 0) {

        int randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS - shipLength);
        int randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS);

        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++ ) {
            ship[randomX + i][randomY] = true;
        }
    } else  {

        int randomX = (int)random(NUM_COLS);
        int randomY = (int)random(NUM_ROWS - shipLength); 

        for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++ ) {
            ship[randomX][randomY+1] = true;
        }
    }
    println(shipLength);
}

void mouseClicked () {

    int cell_x = mouseX / CELLSIZE; 
    int cell_y = mouseY / CELLSIZE;

    if (!click[cell_x][cell_y]) {
        click[cell_x][cell_y] = true;

        if ( ship[cell_x][cell_y] ) {
            hitCount ++;
        } else {
            missCount ++;
        }
    }
}
```